# how can I cache all files forever in .htaccess except .html and .php

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
#tell browser how to deal with compressed content
<Files *.css.gz>
AddType "text/css" .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gz
</Files>

<Files *.js.gz>
AddType "application/javascript" .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gz
</Files>



<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(js|css|png|jpg|ico|pdf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public" 
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>




RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Cache-Friendly File Names
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)\.(.*)$ $1.$3

#try to use precompressed files whenever possible
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ web_inc/$1.css.gz
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ web_inc/$1.js.gz
```

The web page is mostly static .html files and large .js and .css files that use ajax calls for any dynamic content.  Since all files in the html are refereed to by `name-01.js` if I make an update to the .js I just increase the version number and the browser recaches.

I wish to prevent the web browser from ever redownloading any file type except .html or .php.  Is there a way to not have to list every file type I use and how can I explicitly set php to 0 sec for mod_expires?

Comment: idk why no one answered that